# Generate Excel file using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

Is there any simple way to generate an simple excel file using JavaScript?

Best Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to generate Excel through Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333537/how-to-generate-excel-through-javascript)

Comment: why not just do an ajax call instead?

Answer (score 2):

[Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140066(v=office.10).aspx#odc_xmlss_howto) Using spread sheet documentation We can dynamically create spreadsheet using javascript
just follow documentation and add syntax
You refer [this](http://druckit.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/generate-an-excel-file-from-an-ext-js-4-grid/)

```
'<?xml version="1.0"?>',
            '<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">',
            '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Title>' + theTitle + '</Title></DocumentProperties>',
            '<OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><AllowPNG/></OfficeDocumentSettings>',
            '<ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">',
            '<WindowHeight>' + worksheet.height + '</WindowHeight>',
            '<WindowWidth>' + worksheet.width + '</WindowWidth>',
            '<ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>',
            '<ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>',
            '</ExcelWorkbook>',

            '<Styles>',

            '<Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">',
            '<Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>',
            '<Borders/>',
            '<Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000"/>',
            '<Interior/>',
            '<NumberFormat/>',
            '<Protection/>',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="title">',
            '<Borders />',
            '<Font ss:Bold="1" ss:Size="18" />',
            '<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="1" />',
            '<NumberFormat ss:Format="@" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="headercell">',
            '<Font ss:Bold="1" ss:Size="10" />',
            '<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:WrapText="1" />',
            '<Interior ss:Color="#A3C9F1" ss:Pattern="Solid" />',
            '</Style>',


            '<Style ss:ID="even">',
            '<Interior ss:Color="#CCFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid" />',
            '</Style>',


            '<Style ss:ID="evendate" ss:Parent="even">',
            '<NumberFormat ss:Format="yyyy-mm-dd" />',
            '</Style>',


            '<Style ss:ID="evenint" ss:Parent="even">',
            '<Numberformat ss:Format="0" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="evenfloat" ss:Parent="even">',
            '<Numberformat ss:Format="0.00" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="odd">',
            '<Interior ss:Color="#CCCCFF" ss:Pattern="Solid" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="groupSeparator">',
            '<Interior ss:Color="#D3D3D3" ss:Pattern="Solid" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="odddate" ss:Parent="odd">',
            '<NumberFormat ss:Format="yyyy-mm-dd" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="oddint" ss:Parent="odd">',
            '<NumberFormat Format="0" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="oddfloat" ss:Parent="odd">',
            '<NumberFormat Format="0.00" />',
            '</Style>


            '</Styles>
            worksheet.xml,
            '</Workbook>'
```

And atlast encode above xml to base64 and form a data-url start with'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,{base64 encoded above xml}

Atlast it may look like this Please click here to download excel `enter code here`

Answer (score -1):

It's going to be very difficult to generate an *Excel* file, but a CSV file will be easy to build:

```
field1,field2,field3
value1,value2,value3
value1,value2,value3
```

generate it in JavaScript, and send it to the user as a download using [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify):

> Downloadify is a tiny JavaScript + Flash library that enables the generation and saving of files on the fly, in the browser, without server interaction.

Comment: Downvote - this is not what the question is asking.