# Excel generation with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I want to generate that kind of excel : https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6pm6.jpg
(with border style, image, tons of merged cells, ...)
Is it possible using a javascript/JQuery excel library ? 
It did not seem to be the case with Excel Builder, or js-xlsx ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to generate Excel through Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333537/how-to-generate-excel-through-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why shouldn't it be possible with Excel Builder? Just a few seconds of googl'ing...

Creating Worksheets:
http://excelbuilderjs.com/cookbook/creatingWorksheet.html

Fonts and Colors:
http://excelbuilderjs.com/cookbook/fontsAndColors.html

Theming Tables:
http://excelbuilderjs.com/cookbook/themingTables.html

All you need and more, isn't it? Or do you want others to do the work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer , and your oversized ego ; ) I do not find how to choose the cell to put data in. I'm trying since yesterday, but if you find a solution to define areas (cells) of writing , I will be delighted to accept your answer

Comment: Sorry if I sounded too harsh. That information (the specific problem) would have been rather helpful in the original question. Without it, it sounded like "I haven't tried anything myself, but I want it to look like this".

It seems you have to use empty cells, I can't see any function to target a cell directly with something like an X,Y coordinate or a field name like E:23.