# Auto filter not work in Angular application when i want to export excel file

Tags: angular, exceljs

I m using excel js package for exporting excel from angular application.
Everything is working fine except one thing which is auto filtering.
When I use auto filter it does not work.

```
   let workbook: ExcelProper.Workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    sheet = workbook.addWorksheet(dataKey, {
      views: [{ state: 'frozen', xSplit: 3 }],
      pageSetup: { fitToPage: true, fitToHeight: 5, fitToWidth: 7 }
    });
    sheet.autoFilter = 'A1:AY1';
```

Comment: let workbook: ExcelProper.Workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

sheet = workbook.addWorksheet(dataKey,
{ views : [
{state: 'frozen', xSplit: 3}
],
pageSetup: {fitToPage: true, fitToHeight: 5, fitToWidth: 7}
});
sheet.autoFilter = 'A1:AY1';

Comment: Show us the code you have so far and what exactly doesn't work? How does the output look like?

Comment: @somjikatiyar you should add more details in your question. Also adding running examples will be great for us to understand the issue faster and better. You can use [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular) for sharing Angular projects issue samples.

Comment: @SujitKumarSingh i m sending the code which i used in my angular service.Actually excel file which i export are result as expected on window machine but in Linux machine  i am not able to show automatic filter on column

Comment: public exportAsExcelFileFromCropMonitoring(data: any, excelFileName: string): void {
    console.log('export ' );
  
    let workbook: ExcelProper.Workbook  = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook = this.getSheet( workbook , data);
    workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer()
    .then((buffer) => {
      console.log('done');
      // done
      let blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
      saveAs(blob, excelFileName + '.xlsx');
    }).catch( res => {

      console.log('static errorr:', res);
    });
  }

Comment: @somjikatiyar I see [few opened issued regarding AutoFilter](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+filter). I am not sure how to help you on this as I haven't used ExcelJS. But, I can suggest you to either filter out data by your custom logic or use [AlaSQL](https://github.com/agershun/alasql).

Comment: @somjikatiyar you can also look at [my AlaSQL usage answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333537/how-to-generate-excel-through-javascript/44690670#44690670). Also, you may want to look at other possible alternatives in the same question.